# How to use woframscript (Mathematica 11) on Win 10 console command line?

Tags: windows, scripting, version-11

I was trying to understand how to use `wolframscript` (new in Mathematica 11) in a console window on Win 10. I set my Path environment variable to point to the `wolframscript` executable. I opened a console window and enter the following example (directly from the [WolframScript](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) Documentation page):

```
C:\Users\David\Documents\Mathematica\Packages>wolframscript -code 2+2
```

Rather than returning `4`, this command line brings up a Windows Dialog asking for a MathLink program to launch. Canceling out of that returns nothing. The same thing happens when I use the command line for running a WL file (eg. `wolframscript -file WLScriptTest.wl`). This behavior is not shown in the Documentation.

Is there something else I need to do to make this work on Win 10?

Comment: Did you set ``C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.0\`` as a *system* **Path** variable and restarted the PC?  I'm having problems using WolframScript myself ([see chat entry for details](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31669722#31669722)), but `wolframscript -code 2+2` actually works for me in cmd and PowerShell.

Comment: @Karsten7 I set my user Path variable, not the system Path. I'll try setting the system Path and do a restart.

Comment: I just set my system Path and did a restart. The behavior is still as described in my question. I have no idea why it is bringing up a Windows Dialog asking for a MathLink program to launch? The Docs don't mention anything about MathLink.

Comment: @david You shouldn't have to add anything to path other than the location for wolframscript on Windows (it will automagically find the newest version available).  What happens if you run the command line version of the v11 kernel?  (aka wolfram.exe)

Comment: @ihojnicki My v11 kernel console apps (wolfram.exe, wolframkernel.exe) work as described in the Docs.

Comment: @david If you just run wolframscript without any command line arguments, it should look like you just launched the terminal version of the kernel.

Comment: @ihojnicki That is what I inferred from the Docs. However for me, wolframscript without arguments appears to run (doesn't hang or put up a dialog), but immediately exits without presenting the terminal version of the kernel. Since it appears to be working for others, I will probably submit a support request with WRI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking at my personal use license installation of Mathematica 11, I was able to get `wolframscript` to run by modifying the the configuration file at `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Wolfram\WolframScript.conf`. Remove the comment prefix and add the path to `wolfram.exe` as follows:

```
WOLFRAMSCRIPT_KERNELPATH=C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/11.0/wolfram.exe
```

From this, it appears that `wolframscript` is built upon `wolfram.exe`. I'm not sure why this wasn't done automatically on my primary license installation of Mathematica 11. But, now it runs the simple examples I was trying in the documentation.